# Login to a site using PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl

The only problem for me is that it doesn't have a html button for form submit it is using css styled custom button with no name attribute.
This is the form

```
<form name="login_form" method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="loginFormSubmit(this)">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:-1500px;"><input type="submit" value="sub"></div>
        Username:<input name="username" size="20" maxlength="32"><br><br>
        Password:<input type="password" name="passwd" size="20" maxlength="32">
    </form>
```

Button's HTML code which if outside of  tags

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 54px; height: 20px; top: 382px; margin-left: 312px; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;" onmouseover="fFOB(this)" onmouseout="fFNN(this)" onclick="loginFormSubmit(document.login_form)">Login</div>
```

And This is my PHP code

```
    <?php
$username="yyyyy"; 
$password="xxxxx"; 
$url="http://example.com/login.php"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 
$postdata = "username=".$username."&passwd=".$password; 
$postdata = "username=$username&passwd=$password";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I want to login to the site and grab the html of member's area page. Now it is just displaying the login page when I grab the content i.e. its not loggin me in

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to login through php curl which is submited by javascript i.e no submit button in form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308683/how-to-login-through-php-curl-which-is-submited-by-javascript-i-e-no-submit-butt)

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting error, when I grab the content of the site after loggin in it just gives me the html of login page but i want html of members area page.

Answer (score -1):

Change type like,

```
 method = 'get'
```

in form tag and in php code use

```
GET['username'],GET['password']
```